# Extract value from string in file powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search through the newest log file in directory for a particular string. The string reads `Number of days since last service=` and after the equals sign is a number. I want to extract that number for use later in my powershell program. This is what i have so far

```
$logDir= "C:logs\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $logdir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$findStr = Select-String -Path $latest.name -Pattern "Number of days since last service="
```

but now i am stuck. This is what it actually looks like in the log

```
<Msg>Number of days since last service =18</Msg>
```

so what i don't know how to do is extract the number between the equals sign and the `<` for this particular string

Comment: It's great that they're using an XML structured log format, so you don't have to use regular expressions and text slicing to get the data. `:facepalm:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Select-String with regex capture groups.

```
 $Matches = Select-String -Path $latest.name -Pattern "last service =(\d+)" | % {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got your answer by now, but **"Imma giv eya more!"**
Assuming we have these defined ahead of time:

```
$Log = "<Stuff><Msg>Number of days since last service =18</Msg></Stuff>"
$StringHint = "Number of days since last service ="
```

1. Your typical Select-String method of doing things with Regexes. yep.

```
Select-String -InputObject $Log -Pattern "(?<=$StringHint)\d{1,}(?=<)" -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches.Groups[0].Value}
```

2. Doing the splits:

```
((($Log -split $StringHint)[1]) -split "<")[0]
```

3. The XML way.  This only works for XML log files and if there is no other MSG tag (which is unlikely in this case).
I chose to include this because I think it's cool how a simple type cast can dramatically alter how we can work with the data. Plus, it's a really easy way of stripping the nasty <'s and >'s away.

```
$xml = [xml]$Log
$EqualsLoc = $xml.Stuff.Msg.IndexOf("=")
$xml.Stuff.Msg.Substring($EqualsLoc+1)
```

The above would have been even better if you had a log file like this (yes, I know this is a configuration file and not a log file):

```
$XML = [xml]"<Application>
    <version>1.3.53</version>
    <AdvancedSettings>
        <Network>
            <InternetForWeebs>False</InternetForWeebs>
            <HackAllTheSystems>True</HackAllTheSystems>
            <L33tHandle>Gingervitis</L33tHandle>
        </Network>
    </AdvancedSettings>
    <BasicSettings>
        <Controls>
            <TheAnyKeyDesignation>0x42</TheAnyKeyDesignation>
            <CanHazCheeseburgerMode>True</CanHazCheeseburgerMode>
        </Controls>
    </BasicSettings>
    <Diagnostics>
        <DaysSinceLastService>18</DaysSinceLastService>
    </Diagnostics>
</Application>"
```

Then, getting the entry you needed would be something as easy as this:

```
$XML.Application.Diagnostics.DaysSinceLastService
```

Comment: Or if you don't know the path, and just know it's a Msg node, you can use `Select-Xml` as such: `$XML | Select-Xml -XPath './/Msg' | Where{$_.Node.InnerXML -match "(?<=$StringHint)(\d{1,})(?=<)"} | %{$Matches[1]}`

Comment: `\d{1,}` is the same as `\d+` in that it matches one or more occurances.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the string before and after the data you want, you could just the `-Replace` operator to remove the unwanted text:

```
$Days = $findStr -replace '<Msg>Number\ of\ days\ since\ last\ service\ =','' -replace '</Msg>',''
```

Alternatively, since the information is the only number in the string, you could use `-Match` with `\d+` (one or more numbers) to get the value.

```
$findStr -match '\d+'
$Days = $Matches.Values
```

Comment: For your first answer you could more simply do `$Days = $findstr -replace '\<Msg\>Number of days since last service =\s*(\d+).*','$1'`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this

```
$result =[regex]::Match($findStr, '=([^/)]+)<').Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: `Select-String` outputs regex MatchInfo objects, so `$findStr` is already a thing you can use Groups and Value on, if you put the grouping in your select-string regex. (Instead of forcing it back into strings, and matching them as regexes again)